# Unable to login with default business test account in paypal sandbox

Tags: paypal, paypal-sandbox

In the testing guide of paypal API https://www.x.com/developers/paypal/documentation-tools/ug_sandbox it's mentioned in 2 locations

> When you register as a PayPal developer, the Sandbox automatically creates for you a Business test account and its associated test credentials

and

> The Sandbox automatically creates your first Business test account when you sign-up for a Developer account on developer.paypal.com. This gives you a default set of merchant credentials that you can use immediately to test credit-card transactions.

And that's what happened with me when I logged in at the new developer site using a live paypal account I found a business test account created as xxxx-facilitator@xxxx.com. Now I need to login at the sandbox using this account and I couldn't find in the account profile anything regarding the account password so I clicked the "Profile" link and clicked "Change Password" and entered a new password then clicked "Save" and it said "Password Updated" then when I try to login at sandbox.paypal.com it says "Please make sure you enter your email address and password correctly"

Comment: having the same problem. isn't it solved yet?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We are currently working to resolve this issue in Sandbox. If you attempt to reset your password from the application page in developer.paypal.com it does not actually change the password for that sandbox account. As a workaround, you can create a new business account by clicking the "Create Account" button at the top of the page. A fix is scheduled tonight to resolve this issue. I will update my answer as soon as this is resolved. Sorry for the inconvenience.

**Update:** This issue is now resolved.

Thanks,

Comment: Thanks, I've already tried creating a new business account and I can login at the sandbox with it but the issue is that the API credentials of any test account other than the default one are not accepted, when I use them I get an error, only the credentials of the default account are accepted so I am forced to use it so that's why I need its password. I guess this is another issue you need to fix.

Comment: Are you getting a specific error? I have tested a few new business accounts this morning and the API credentials seem to be working. Let me know how I can help clear up the error you are receiving.

Comment: Yes I get this error "We are unable to complete your request at this time. Please try again later. We apologize for the inconvenience." Whenever I use the API credentials (username,password, signature) of any business account I create. I am using the express checkout API.

Comment: I posted a question with this issue: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15530692/paypal-api-credentials-error-in-express-checkout

Comment: You should now be able to change the password for your facilitator account without any issues.

Comment: Thanks it's now working, I have changed the password and finally managed to login into the sandbox using the facilitator account.

Comment: i can't belive that how paypal is buggy on live

Comment: I have same problem.. I am getting problem with my facilitator account. Can anybody suggest me at which url should I login with this credential.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem with some testing accounts I imported through the new developer site.
There seems to be a problem handling the different sessions: the developer session when you login with your developer account and the test merchant account you use to login in the sandbox area.. as you can see from the many similar questions this is affecting many users...

Comment: Yes I noticed a lot of questions regarding the new developer site, this is very frustrating as it caused us delays in our development because we can't test anything.